# Check control in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am needing that if there is no `CheckBox` selected in the `DataGridView` the button Uno and the button Varios are disabled.
If a single `CheckBox` is selected, the `button` Uno is enabled and the `button` Varios disabled.
And if there is more than one `CheckBox` selected, the `button` Uno is disabled and the `button` Varios is enabled.

But, the following happens:

[image]

The code I use is the following:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    btnUno.Enabled = false;
    btnVarios.Enabled = false;
}
```

To enable and disable the buttons:

```
private void dtgTitulo_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int contador = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgTitulo.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["Seleccione"].Value != null && row.Cells["Seleccione"].Value.Equals(true))//Columna de checks
        {
            contador++;
            if (contador <= 0)
            {
                btnUno.Enabled = false;
                btnVarios.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (contador == 1)
            {
                btnUno.Enabled = true;
                btnVarios.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                btnUno.Enabled = false;
                btnVarios.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me? Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**
**HOW TO I LOAD THE DATAGRIDVIEW WITH CHECKBOXES:**

```
private DataTable Query()
        {
            DataTable datos = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("STRING");
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                string consulta = "SELECT Titulo AS Título FROM V_CuetaWeb GROUP BY titulo ORDER BY titulo DESC";
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(consulta, sqlConn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);//este se encarga de inicializar el command
                da.Fill(datos);
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            return datos;
        }
```

I form_Load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ds = new DataSet(); 
            ds.Tables.Add(Query());
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Seleccione", typeof(bool));
            dtgTitulo.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
```

Comment: Try writing your enable disable code after the foreach loop

Comment: not works, the same error happens as in the gif I showed @Lucifer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after click on checkboxes they show/hide ticks, but value in cell doesn't change immediately. call `EndEdit` to apply them.

```
private void dtgTitulo_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || dtgTitulo.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != "Seleccione")
        return;
    dtgTitulo.EndEdit();

    int contador = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgTitulo.Rows)
    {
        if (Equals(true, row.Cells["Seleccione"].Value))
        {
            contador++;
            if (contador > 1)
                break;
        }
    }

    btnUno.Enabled = contador == 1;
    btnVarios.Enabled = contador > 1;
}
```

p.s. note optimizations made to avoid unnecessary iterations

Comment: do you use `CellContentClick` event?

Comment: You're right, I was doing it on the cellvaluechanged. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code:

AS per @JIMI's suggestion

```
private void dtgTitulo_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.ColumnIndex != 1) return; 

     dtgTitulo.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit); 

     var contador  = dtgTitulo.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Count(r => (r.Cells[1].Value != null) && ((bool)r.Cells[1].Value == true));

     if (contador <= 0)
     {
          btnUno.Enabled = false;
          btnVarios.Enabled = false;
     }
     else
     {
          if (contador == 1)
          {
              btnUno.Enabled = true;
              btnVarios.Enabled = false;
          }
          else
          {
              btnUno.Enabled = false;
              btnVarios.Enabled = true;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: @FrancoJoelBalsamo please see above code change your event to cell value changed and make sure your enable/disable code is right

Comment: In `CellMouseUp`, add the following: `if (e.ColumnIndex != 1) return;
dtgTitulo.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
var cellCount = dtgTitulo.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Count(r => (r.Cells[1].Value != null) && ((bool)r.Cells[1].Value == true));` The Cell.Value is changed only when you move the selection to another cell, so you may want to commit the change before counting.

Comment: `System.InvalidCastException: 'The specified conversion is invalid.'` 
In this line: 
`(r.Cells[1].Value != null) && ((bool)r.Cells[1].Value == true)).ToString()`

Comment: @Franco Joel Balsamo  Why do you have `.ToString()` there?